# Case return null when result query is empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to initialize variable from table, but when result of query returns 0 row case expression is not working, for example:

```
do $$
declare _reportId bigint := null;
        _serviceId bigint := null; 
begin

    _serviceId := 12;
    _reportId := null;

    select  case when _serviceId is null then rp.value::bigint else _serviceId end
    into    _serviceId
    from    rep.reportparameters as rp
    where   rp.reportid = _reportId;

    RAISE NOTICE '%', _serviceId;
end;
$$;
```

So in this variant of parameters i need  `_serviceId` value 12  (because result of query returns 0 row, is no reportId with null in table). But i have `null` value for `_serviceId`

Analog construction in SQL Server work great, they return 12 for `@serviceId`:

```
DECLARE @reportId bigint = NULL, 
        @serviceId bigint = null; 

SET @serviceId = 12;

SELECT  CASE when @serviceId is null then rp.[value] else @serviceId end
from    rep.reportparameters as rp
where   rp.reportid = @reportId;

SELECT @serviceId
```

Why in PostgreSql case not working?

Comment: you can see the explanation in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) in the section Compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW), if no row is returned, then the INTO assignment will set the variable to NULL. The CASE expression is never evaluated if no row is selected, so it can't change a NULL value into something different.

You can use `coalesce()` with a direct assignment instead:

```
do $$
declare 
  _reportId bigint := null;
  _serviceId bigint := null; 
begin

    _reportId := null;
    _serviceid := 12;
    _serviceid := coalesce((select rp.value::bigint
                            from rep.reportparameters as rp
                            where rp.reportid = _reportId), _serviceid);

    RAISE NOTICE '%', _serviceId;
end;
$$;
```